# Katz Centrality

Tags: graph-theory, network

M.E.J. Newman's *Networks* Book defines the *Katz Centrality* as:

$$ x = \left(\mathbf{I} - \alpha A \right)^{-1}\mathbf{1}  $$

, wheras in - P. Bonacich, P. Lloyd (2001), *Eigenvector-like measures of centrality for asymmetric relations*, Social Networks - the same centrality definition is called *Alpha-Centrality*.
Also there a *Katz Centrality* is mentioned, which is defined as:

$$ x = \left( \left(\mathbf{I} - \alpha A \right)^{-1} - \mathbf{I} \right)\mathbf{1}  $$

Is there meanwhile a canonical naming for these centrality measures established?

Answer (score 1):

Both formulas mean the same, and it is a simple case of alpha centrality.
The first formula is derived in such way: the matrix of discounted total numbers of all paths (walks) is calculated as  a^{0}A^{0}+a^{1}A^{1}+a^{2}A^{2}+a^{3}A^{3}+...
Here elements (i,j) of the matrix A^1 are numbers of 1-step paths connecting i and j, elements of A^2 are numbers of 2-step paths, etc. But A^0=I in the sum is written only for commodity; really there are no 0-step paths. 
That is why in the second formula this term is excluded: (-I).
In other words, the difference between the indices given by the two formulas for each node i is x(i)-x(i)=1.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I know the differences between these definitions, but still I don't know how they are called in the literature. You think both are called alpha centrality?